# Image manipulations in Universal Windows app

Tags: c#, image, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have an image element inside a grid along with other controls in it. I want to be able to zoom the image. I don't want to place it inside a scroll viewer as I don't know the dimensions of the image and as it is a Universal app, I am having a lot of Adpative UI and the ScrollViewer messes with whole thing. The Image is downloaded from the web. When the user swipes left or right the source of the image should change to previous or next image. I am saving the sources of the images in a LinkedList and updating the source accordingly.

I implemented the swipe to change image source using the following code

```
MediaControl.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
        MediaControl.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) => { X1 = (int)e.Position.X; Y1 = (int)e.Position.Y; };
        MediaControl.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) => {
            X2 = (int)e.Position.X;
            Y2 = (int)e.Position.Y;
            if (Math.Abs(X1 - X2) >= 50 && Math.Abs(Y1 - Y2) < 20)
            {
                {
                    if (X1 > X2)
                    {
                        NextPostButton_Click(s, e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PreviousPostButton_Click(s, e);
                    }
                }
            };
        };
```

I want to have zoom functionality in my image at the same time when source is changed, the image should be zoomed out. I want both the zoom and swipe functionality without each affecting the other manipulation. How do I do this? I am a beginner and have no experience in very complex Pointer events. If anyone could help me with this or point me to a good source for learning about this I would be eternally grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the ManipulationDelta event, and use ManipulationDelta.Scale Property to take care of the zoom.

```
    MediaControl.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.Scale | ManipulationModes.TranslateX;

    private void MediaControl_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaControl.Height = e.Delta.Scale * MediaControl.ActualHeight;
        MediaControl.Width = e.Delta.Scale * MediaControl.ActualWidth;
    }
```

For more information on ManipulationDelta, see to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationdelta.scale(v=vs.110).aspx

For more information on ManipulationModes, see to
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationmodes

Answer (score 0):

Use a FlipView with a ScrollViewer inside of it and an Image inside of that. Then you just bind your FlipView's ItemsSource to a collection of Uri's. This will keep zoom functionality and swipe functionality automatically. Each image will retain its zoom factor as you swipe through your images. This works very well on mobile and desktops/tablets.

Let me know if you need some sample code. I'm on a phone right now so it's a little difficult to do source.